# How to define default values for HTML form elements without populating the field?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, frontend

I have a huge form with many text boxes. Not all are mandatory but I dont want it to send `undefined`  to my backend since many are of type `integer` and `float`.I need to define default values for all of them but I don't want the users to have to delete the default values before entering theirs everytime. The default values show up if I do `value="defaultVal"` in the `<input>...</input>` tag. I tried providing `placeholder="..."` but still `value` overrides `placeholder`. Any suggestions to achive this?

Comment: You want to do that server side. However you could evaluate all the inputs before submitting.

Comment: I think you're trying to solve the wrong problem. If a field that they don't fill in is sending undefined to the server-side/backend code, that sounds like a problem with both the code that sends the values in the client *and* the server-side code that handles those values.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist  This is my Model attribute : 
 `targetAmount: {
 type: 'integer',
        defaultsTo: 0
  },`
 This is the part of form which takes the input:    
 `<label>Target Amount:</label><br>
 <input class="form-control" type="number" name="targetAmount"/>`

 I get an error on submission as follows: 
`Invalid attributes sent to Property:
  targetAmount
    'undefined' should be a integer (instead of "NaN", which is a number)`

Answer (score 0):

you can set the default value as you have been, and then just clear the input field onFocus, so that the user can enter into a fresh slate

Answer (score -1):

You can try this:

```
<input type="text" onfocus="if(this.value == 'value') { this.value = ''; }" value="value" />
```

[Source code](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/javascript/clear-field-on-focus/)